# How to configure "Config File Provider Plugin" programatically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to automate the provisioning of the Jenkins instance.

My current pipeline depends on a config file being managed by the "**Config File Provider Plugin**".

I need to know how to add the new config file as part of the Jenkins init hook (`init.groovy.d`)

Comment: Are you using [JCasC](https://plugins.jenkins.io/configuration-as-code/)? Much easier approach.

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to switch to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
configFiles {
    groovyScript {
        id("Jenkinsfile")
        name("Jenkinsfile")
        comment("Jenkinsfile to be used by pipeline-multibranch-defaults plugin")
        content("""
            library identifier: 'ci-pipeline@master',
                    retriever: modernSCM([\$class: 'GitSCMSource', remote: 'https://github.com/ci-pipeline/ci-pipeline.git'])
            
            node {
              checkout scm
              ci('.ci-pipeline.yaml')
            }
        """)
    }
}
```

see:

http://<your jenkins domain>/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html#path/configFiles